# Selenium WebDriver IE Browser open display security setting page and closed

Tags: java, selenium

My automation testing for IE display security testing page and closed. What is the problem?

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + ".//src//driver//IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        // this line of code is to resolve protected mode issue capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("https://10.204.137.86:5111/prweb/PRWebLDAP3/");
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console.

Comment: refer this : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/automation-using-internet-explorer-11-pritam-maske/